# Is there a tool to add multiple images to Tridion?

Tags: 2011, image

Adding template images (e.g. referenced in the css) into Tridion one by one is time consuming. I there a tool that will upload multiple images at once?

Comment: Webdav is the way to go here...

Comment: Not exactly a tool, but Jonathan Whiteside posted two articles on handling [code](http://blog.building-blocks.com/publishing-code-files-from-sdl-tridion) and [CSS files](http://blog.building-blocks.com/css-in-sdl-tridion-part-2-handling-image-references) with Tridion's APIs. Be sure to read the comments as well, which echo some of the answers below.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is also a tool in the Tridion PowerTools project

I believe it is working: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/BatchImageUploader

Comment: The only set back I've found with that power tool is that it seems to work on the assumption that you're uploading from a PC. However, I do think it's the most ideal solution for this situation.

Answer (score 15):

You can upload multiple images using webdav... Copy paste via windows explorer. Setting the default schema on the folder will define what MM schema they use.

To make a Webdav connection you can create a network connection to your CMS server using `http://servername/webdav`

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to WebDav, the 2011 Power Tools project includes a Batch Image Uploader:

https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/

Comment: Beat you by 1 minute :)

Comment: So you did! Must spam F5 faster.

Answer (score 10):

We can create a short utility by using the core services to upload the CSS images.

Even, we can create more generic utility for CSS file which will only upload those css images which are using in css files.

Comment: Hi Priyank, might it be useful for future visitors if you could provide a code snippet to illustrate how to perform this kind of automated component creation using the Core Service?

Answer (score 9):

When using Dreamweaver, you could have it upload all your images referenced in your DWT templates by uploading the dependent files. Dreamweaver uses WebDAV for the actual upload, so the manual way of doing that would be to just use the WebDAV Windows Explorer interface (where you can drag and drop multiple files).

If you would like something else then the [Batch Image Uploader](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/BatchImageUploader) in the Tridion Power Tools project would be an option

Comment: [I have a video showing this approach](http://www.createandbreak.net/2012/01/quickly-start-layout-template-building.html). If the references don't update the first time, pasting into a WebDAV folder the second usually fixes them.

Answer (score 7):

though I know others have already answered the question by suggesting Power Tools, I'd like to address something else.

If your need is specifically images referenced in the CSS file, then these images probably aren't 'content', are they? I would think that images called from CSS are presentational in nature, and will be called, therefore, every time a page loads; this can poorly affect performance for the end-user. Why not make a single image sprite, and load that file?

I know it would seem time consuming, but Adobe Fireworks CS6 has a sprite-making functionality, where you add all of the images, slice and name them, and it generates a CSS file for you and builds an optimized sprite.  I've used it several times (in Tridion implementations) to save the burden of having multiple presentational images to manage in Tridion.

Answer (score 4):

I realise that I'm a bit late to this party, but you may want to consider using [@UI-Beardcore](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/206/ui-beardcore)'s MultipleUpload bookmarklet:

http://tridion.uibeardcore.com/2014/07/tools-multipleupload/#bookmarklet

This is one of many bookmarklets submitted to [the Tridion Bookmarklet challenge](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324/the-tridion-bookmarklet-challenge) and is a great example of providing really easy to use functionality by extending the Tridion interface through bookmarklets.

Comment: This is awesome...good stuff by Orlov